# Numpy Rebin 2 columns dataset

Tags: python, numpy, dataset, 2d, binning

I have a datafile of many different columns that I load into an numpy array and I just load 2 columns out of it. So far so good (I checked by printing on screen and saving to another file and this works fine). My goal now that I have a XY dataset is to rebin the data in order to kinda smooth it out. I am absolutely clueless on how to do this. Can anyone help?

Thank you very much.